# change <a> target to "_blank" depending on href

Tags: javascript, href, target, getelementsbytagname

I'm trying to sort through the links on my page and make some of them open into a new window, depending on their URL.  This is the code I have.  It doesn't seem to be working.  Can you see why?

```
function MakeMenuLinksOpenInNewWindow() {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        if (links[i].href == "http://testtesttest.org/")
            links[i].target = "_blank";
    }
}
MakeMenuLinksOpenInNewWindow();
```

Comment: Can you show some HTML to go with it?

Comment: Did you try links[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank') instead of links[i].target = "_blank";
Maybe that will work.

Comment: No, it won't. Please don't use `getAttribute`/`setAttribute` for scripting HTML documents. They are less readable than the normal DOM Level 1 HTML properties like `href=` and they're buggy in IE.

Comment: use example.com (org, net, or edu) for examples. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery.js. It'll make your life much easier:

```
$("a[href='http://testtesttest.org/']").attr("target", "_blank");
```

Comment: his javascript is fine. telling him to replace it with the equivalent jquery won't fix his problem.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably not be setting this javascript. And instead use HTML.

But if you must...

```
function MakeMenuLinksOpenInNewWindow() {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0, l = links.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (links[i].href === "http://www.example.com/")
            links[i].target = "_blank";
    }
}
window.onload = MakeMenuLinksOpenInNewWindow;
```

Comment: I put this into my .js file, and it doesn't seem to be working.  Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: also, you may be overriding the window.onload event.

Comment: function MakeMenuLinksOpenInNewWindow() {
    var linkies = document.links;
    for (var i = 0; i < linkies.length; i++) {
        if (linkies[i].href == "http://byupas.org/")
            linkies[i].target = "_blank";
    }
 alert("HEY SUCKA");
}
window.onload = MakeMenuLinksOpenInNewWindow;

The function is definitely not being called, since the Alert is not displaying.

Comment: Using Firebug, I can see that the onload handler is picking up the function, but the DOM inspector says "__onloadStarted" and "onLoadCompleteStarted" are false, long after the page is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that when you call this function the DOM has been loaded:

```
window.onload = MakeMenuLinksOpenInNewWindow;
```

or:

```
<body onload="MakeMenuLinksOpenInNewWindow();">
```

Comment: Is there a way to call the function from the .js file?

Comment: The reason your function did not work is because the DOM (and therefore the a links) had not yet loaded so your script had nothing to do. What Darin's code does is bind your function to the execution of the onload event of the document (in other words, once the DOM is loaded and ready, your function executes). If you add the first code snippet he suggested to your .js file, everything should work.

Comment: Yes, try my first suggestion: `window.onload = MakeMenuLinksOpenInNewWindow;`.

Comment: But other than that, the function is good?

This is what I have in the .js file now:

function MakeMenuLinksOpenInNewWindow() {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        if (links[i].href == "http://byupas.org/")
            links[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    }
 window.onload = MakeMenuLinksOpenInNewWindow();
}

Comment: You could just load .js file as the last element on the page isntead of doing an onload.

Comment: Seriously, we're still recommending `onload`...?

Comment: @J-P - lol. For someone wanting to find all links on the page and change thier target attribute with JS, yes.

Comment: @christian: it should be `window.onload = MakeMenuLinksOpenInNewWindow;`, not `window.onload = MakeMenuLinksOpenInNewWindow();`.

Comment: @David, why?? What part of that requires 'onload'? Why not just place the JS at the bottom of the doc...?

Comment: Using Firebug, I can see that the onload handler is picking up the function, but the DOM inspector says "__onloadStarted" and "onLoadCompleteStarted" are false, long after the page is loaded.

Comment: @J-P. I was first to suggest placing the file at the button of the doc. I just don't think the OP WANTS to do that.

Answer (score 0):

your javascript looks fine. assuming you're having problems with your link elements not existing before you try to modify them, you need to delay running your method as mentioned in other posts. my preferred method is moving the script contents to the end of the page.

since it looks like you're using an external js file, your page would like

```
    ... 
    <a href="http://testtesttest.org/" >whatever</a>
    ... 
    <script src="myscriptfile.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

if you're still having problems, you'll have to post a more complete example.

edits: another point. if you're still having problems, make sure the url you are expecting in the `href` property isn't being rewritten. for example, IE will tack a trailing `/` to the end of a .com url if you don't provide it, which would cause your comparison to fail.